# Laravel API only returning the latest record instead of all records under the user as shown in the database

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, api

I have a React front-end application with a Laravel backend that is linked via API. 
When calling the API to show me the number of visas under 1 user, it only returns 1 record (the last record for that user under the table). I need it to return all visas under the user_id.

Requests/ListVisas.php

```php
use App\Helper\FormRequest;
class ListVisas extends FormRequest {
    public function authorize() {
        return $this->user();
    }
}
```

Controllers/VisaController.php

```php
use App\Http\Requests\ListVisas;
use App\Models\Visa;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Transformers\VisaTransformer;
use App\Transformers\UserTransformer;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class VisasController extends Controller {
    public function list(ListVisas $request, User $user) {
        $visas = $user->visas();
        return VisaTransformer::list($visas);
    }
}
```

Transformers/VisaTransformer.php

```php
use App\Helper\Transformer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class VisaTransformer {
    use Transformer;
    public function listTransformer(Request $request, $row) {
        return [
            "user_id" => $row->user_id,
            "country" => $row->country,
            "visa_type" => $row->visa_type,
            "entry_type" => $row->entry_type,
            "date_expiry" => $row->date_expiry,
            "status" => $row->status,
            "is_paid" => $row->is_paid,
            "date_review" => $row->date_review,
            "date_lodged" => $row->date_lodged,
            "date_decision" => $row->date_decision,
        ];
    }
}
```

Models/Visa.php

```php
class Visa extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'country',
        'visa_type',
        'entry_type',
        'date_expiry',
        'status',
        'is_paid',
        'date_review',
        'date_lodged',
        'date_decision'
    ];
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Models/User.php

```php
public function visas() {
    return $this->hasMany(Visa::class);
}
```

When the API is called I get the following response:
`{type: "visas/LIST_VISAS_SUCCESS", response: {…}, status: 200}`

```
auth: {id: 1, userId: 1, role: "applicant", email: "yuri@email.com", first_name: "Yuri", …}
...
visas:
  1:
    undefined:
    country: "Vietnam"
    date_decision: null
    date_expiry: null
    date_lodged: null
    date_review: null
    entry_type: "single"
    is_paid: null
    status: "active"
    user_id: 1
    visa_type: "tourist"
...
```

In the table there are 2 records for this user:

```
--------------------------------------
| id | user_id | country | visa_type | ...
--------------------------------------
| 1  |    2    |  India  |  tourist  | ...
--------------------------------------
| 2  |    2    | Vietnam |  tourist  | ...
---------------------------------
```

Only the last record is fetched from the database instead of all records.

Comment: Could you add your `VisaTransformer::list()` function definition please?

Comment: It's above under Transformers/VisaTransformer.php

Comment: I think they are asking for the `App\Helper\Transformer` trait, which presumably contains the `list()` method.  Also, you're sure it isn't soft-deleted, right?